# ¿Cómo cuento los espacios en blanco usando un ciclo for y charAt(x) en java?

Tags: java, array, string

Tengo el siguiente código, para mostrar por ciclo y letra por letra, el contenido en cada indice del array `caracter`:

```
Scanner ins = new Scanner(System.in);

          String caracter;

          System.out.println("Ingrese cualquier palabra o frase");
          caracter = ins.next();


          for (int indice=0;indice<=caracter.length();indice++){
              System.out.println(caracter.charAt(indice));
          }
```

Funciona correctamente con palabras o cadenas de caracteres consecutivas, pero, cuando ingreso una frase compuesta con espacios y palabras, después de recorrer el ciclo, el programa salta con un error en el indice que le corresponde al espacio en blanco:
[image]

Según el error, me da a entender que a partir de la palabra *Le*, todo lo que haya por delante, no es posible capturarlo con el método `charAt(x)`. Y si es imposible, ¿Existe otra forma para hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay dos cosas que tienes que cambiar:

- **La primera:** Utiliza el método `nextLine()`, en vez de `next()`. Ya que el primero lee espacios en blanco y el segundo no. Por eso solo le la primera palabra.
- **La segunda:** La excepción salta debido a que no defines bien el bucle. Es `indice<caracter.length()`, y no `indice<=caracter.length()`.

Todo junto:

```
Scanner ins = new Scanner(System.in);

          String caracter;

          System.out.println("Ingrese cualquier palabra o frase");
          caracter = ins.nextLine();


          for (int indice=0;indice<caracter.length();indice++){
              System.out.println(caracter.charAt(indice));
          }
```

Comment: Listo! Era mas sencillo de lo que parece... Muchas gracias.